# moment.js clock that always shows time in Denmark

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I have a small problem with moment.js

What I want to do is to make a clock that always shows the current time in Denmark on a website, no matter where there client is loading my site from.

This is my script (without html):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    startTime();

});

function startTime() {
    var today = new Date( moment().tz("europe/copenhagen") ); 
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var mm = today.getMonth();
    mm = mm + 1;
    var d = today.getDate();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('watch2').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    document.getElementById('watch1').innerHTML =
    d + "/" + mm + "/" + y;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}
```

I have checked using www.geopeeker.com and all locations shows different time, not the current time in Denmark.

Comment: well you have `new Date( moment().tz("europe/copenhagen") )` in your script

Comment: You are not really using moment.js in your code. You just build a standard JavaScript `Date` object where different methods produce output in different time zones, as documented, but only in UTC and browser's time zone.

Comment: Sandeep, your comment really dont add anything to this issue, please consider what you are writing. Alvaro, ok, cant you give a hint how to use moment.js in my code?

Comment: No, I cannot, I've never used that library myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using native JavaScript Date object, instead of take advantage of `moment-timezone`.

Note that `new Date(dateString);` gives time in local time as stated [here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specifed arguments represent local time. If UTC is desired, use n`ew Date(Date.UTC(...))` with the same arguments.

In your case it's better to use moment object and get rid of native JavaScript object.

Moreover, you can use moment [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) instead of calculate yourself how to display time.

Here a working solution:

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = moment.tz("Europe/Copenhagen"); 
  document.getElementById('watch2').innerHTML = today.format('HH:mm:ss');
  document.getElementById('watch1').innerHTML = today.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

startTime();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>

<div id="watch1"></div>
<div id="watch2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, but I still don't know why my first script is not working, how could I use moment.js in my original code?

Comment: @droid edited my answer to add details to explain why `new Date` didn't work. The code in my answer shows how to use moment to get what you need.